# can I change the color of a cell in hands on table after using the after change callback on that cell ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

This is the code that I have tried, can I change the color of the cell when the entered new values's size is grater than 6 digits.

```
var hot = new Handsontable(example1, {
data: data,
colHeaders: true,
rowHeaders: true,
contextMenu: true,
columns: [{},
                    {type : 'numeric', format: '0,0'},
                    {type : 'numeric', format: '0,0'},
                    {type : 'numeric', format: '0,0'}],
hiddenRows: {
  rows: [3, 5, 9],
  indicators: true
}
});

var logicalErrorsRenderer = function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value,    cellProperties) {
Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
td.style.background = 'red';
};

var rowsWithErrorData = [];
hot.updateSettings({
afterChange: function(changes, source){
        console.log(source);
    if(source === "edit")
        console.log(changes);
    var row = changes[0][0];
    var columnN = changes[0][1];
    var oldValue = changes[0][2];
    var newValue = changes[0][3];
    var lengthofNewValue = newValue.toString().length;
    console.log("length of changed Value"+ lengthofNewValue );
    console.log("lets think A column  is fixed or text field like in our case");
    if(columnN >= 1){
        if(isNaN(newValue) && lengthofNewValue >= 6){//**here I want to change the color of this particular cell**
       renderer: logicalErrorsRenderer
      }
    }
    console.log("In after changes methods" + hot.getDataAtRow(row));
    console.log(rowsWithErrorData);
   }
   })
```

Here I am using the hands on table call back "after Change" and doing some validations like if the value is a number or not and pushing those rows which has errors into an error, and I want to high light that cell which doesn't satisfy these constraints in red.

Comment: what's returned in your console.log for 'row' and 'nolumnN' ? ie are the returned parameters at this stage correct in testing?

Comment: yes, I am getting the values of the rows and columns of the particular changed cell.

Comment: let me know what happens with the answer below so it can be adjusted accordingly. ordinarily I'd use a fiddle, but in this case there's a little guesswork. it's a jquery solution (as the question is also marked jQuery) so be sure the library is also in effect.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the handsontable [cell styling](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.24.1/tutorial-styling.html#page-cell) documentation, suggest substituting a little jquery for your js style line:

```
td.style.background = 'red';
```

using a jquery line like:

```
$('.ht_master').find(td).css({ background: 'white' }); // reset all cells
$('.ht_master tr').eq(row).find('td').eq(td).css({ background: 'red' }); // find and set the appropriate cell
```

you may need to add or subtract to `td` and `row` before passing the variable into the above to reach the right cell. This is to automate the equivalent CSS selector method as described in the documentation:

```
.ht_master tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, we can by using beforeValidate call back on the hands on table container

```
          beforeValidate: function(val, row, prop){
            console.log(prop);
            if((prop) === "employeeCount"){ //All Employees count length should not exceed 7
                if(isNaN(val) || val.toString().length > 7 || val < 0){
                    return 'invalid'
                }else {
                    return 0
                };
            }
```